# Can I make a 'Virtualbox' Guest OS see and use directories and files from the Host OS?

Tags: virtualbox, directory, virtualhost

I was researching it and read somewhere that you can, but that was ages ago and I can't find it now so here I am on here.

Comment: What's __the real problem__? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Share a folder through guest configuration.

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders

That should do the trick

Comment: I just tried that, and it didn't work. Anything else?